# What is the reasoning behind exporting from another module?

Tags: javascript, export, es6-modules

Why can you export from another module?

```
export * from …;
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
```

If the importing module/script does indeed need features from a third module, then it can import those itself. So why shouldn't it? I don't really see the purpose of this feature. Does this anything other than create confusion where exactly functions, classes, etc. are located?

Comment: I’ve used it to collect the default exports from multiple files and then export them as named exports in a root file of a module. Handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows for greater modular organization. For example, say you're creating a library for which consumers are expecting to be able to import everything from the root `index.js` of the library. By using `export .. from`, you can write functions with related functionality in the same file (or in the same folder), *and then*, in the `index.js`, export them all at once, despite being spread out all over the codebase.

This is easier than having to tell consumers of the library carefully look up exactly which sub-module they'd need to import a particular object from.